# How to configure Snort 3 to detect nmap's port scanning?

Tags: nmap, ports, snort

How to configure snort 3 to detect nmap's port scanning? For instance I want to know that an external machine A is looking with nmap for open ports on my machine B.
Such a port scan can include all ports incl. of the services available behind it with version (see nmap -A ). If port scanning is dectected I want to log it into a log file.

Please not that I'm interested in snort 3 configuration, not snort 2. For snort 2 there are a lot available docs and tutorials.

Comment: You didn't specify which specific scans you want to detect or whether you want to detect all of them

Comment: snort comes with port scanning rules built-in. Have you looked up the documentation?

Comment: and a single google search returns more options than you can shake a stick at: https://www.google.com/search?q=snort+detect+nmap+scan

Comment: @schroeder I am looking for snort 3 configuration. Google search provide me snort 2 configurations.

Comment: and here's the handy manual for how to convert snort 2 rules to snort 3: https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/596/original/Rules_Writers_Guide_to_Snort_3_Rules.pdf ...

Comment: @SirMuffington I edited my question.